# Auto suggestion input box are not showing value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a problem with auto-suggestion when I search for any username they are coming but when I click one of them they are not showing in my input box when I click on inspect device toolbar(responsive device) it is showing, but without the developer tool(full screen) is not showing. I am using Reactjs18 and a dummy API here to get the username from the JSON placeholder.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

const AutoComplete = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadUser = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );

      const data = await response.json();
      setUsers(data);
    };

    loadUser();
  }, []);
  const onSuggestHandler = (value) => {
    setText(value);

    setSuggestions([]);
  };

  const onChangeHandler = (value) => {
    let matches = [];

    if (value.length > 0) {
      matches = users.filter((user) => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`${value}`, "gi");

        return user.name.match(regex);
      });
    }
    setSuggestions(matches);
    setText(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        <input
          className="input"
          type="text"
          value={text}
          onChange={(event) => onChangeHandler(event.target.value)}
          onBlur={() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              setSuggestions([]);
            }, 100);
          }}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="container-user">
        {suggestions &&
          suggestions.map((suggestion) => (
            <div
              key={suggestion.id}
              className="user"
              onClick={() => onSuggestHandler(suggestion.name)}
            >
              {suggestion.name}
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AutoComplete;
```

Comment: could it be because of your styling? When dumping your code in a codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-hermann-uct30o?file=/src/AutoComplete.js) it works as you describe